# change aspect ratio of scatterplot3d

Tags: r, scatterplot3d

I tried to create a perfect square 3d scatter plot just like figure 1, using methods such as png(width=500, height=500), or par(pty = "s"), or by adjusting parameters "angle" and "asp" in scatterplot3d. However, still plot something like figure2. My goal was to establish specific aspect ratios: x/y=2, x/z=2, and y/z=1. Unfortunately, the 'asp' parameter did not allow multiple inputs. [image]

```
library(scatterplot3d)
set.seed(123)
pc1 <- rnorm(100)
pc2 <- rnorm(100)
pc3 <- rnorm(100)
groups <- sample(c('Bread', 'Durum', 'Spelt'), 100, replace = TRUE)

# Create a data frame with the PC values and group labels
data <- data.frame(PC1 = pc1, PC2 = pc2, PC3 = pc3, Group = groups)

# Define colors for each group
colors <- c('Bread' = 'pink', 'Durum' = 'lightgreen', 'Spelt' = 'skyblue')

# Set up a square plotting window
png("test.png", width = 500, height = 500)
par(c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1), pty = "s")

# Create a 3D scatter plot with square size points
scatterplot3d(data$PC1, data$PC2, data$PC3, color = colors[data$Group],
          pch = 19, type = "p", grid = TRUE,
          xlab = "PC1 (11.63%)", ylab = "PC2 (7.03%)", zlab = "PC3 (4.09%)",
          mar=c(5,3,4,3)+0.1,
          angle=45,
          asp = 0.5)

 # Manually add group annotations without outside box
 legend("topright", legend = unique(data$Group), col = unique(colors), pch = 19, bty = "n",  inset = c(0.1,0), xpd=TRUE, ncol=1)

 dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think `scatterplot3d` supports that.  You could try `rgl::plot3d` which is more flexible (it would allow `aspect = c(2, 1, 1)` for the ratios you want).  There's also `plot3D::scatter3D` and `plot3Drgl::scatter3Drgl`; the latter definitely supports aspect changes, I'm not sure about the former.

Comment: Scatterplot3d is using base graphics which has no built in support for 3D. So ’asp’ could not be used. Similarly png has no understanding of the size of the plot area or axes. Furthermore you haven’t said what you mean be “square” in the context of a perspective pseudo-3D image.

Comment: Thank you all! Problem was solved by just setting scale.y=.75 and adjusting width and height ratio when outputting, still using scatterplot3d.